# Camel Casing in Module Namespace

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, configuration

Is it possible to create a Magento extension with a camelcase in the namespace?

Something like `SmashingMagazine_Wishlist`, I saw this article doing it The [Basics Of Creating A Magento Module](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/basics-creating-magento-module/).

But would this cause any problems with the Mage AutoLoader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You just need to make sure to do it everywhere.

- Directory: `SmashingMagazine_Wishlist`
- Classes: `SmashingMagazine_Wishlist_Model_ClassName`
- Node in `etc/modules/SmashingMagazine_Wishlist.xml`: `config/modules/SmashingMagazine_Wishlist`
- Node values in `config.xml`: `global/blocks/smashingMagazine_wishlist/class`: `SmashingMagazine_Wishlist_Block`

And be VERY careful if you develop under Mac OS X or Windows with case **IN** sensitive file system. After deployment on a linux box your code might not work, because of a case mistake.

Comment: Yeah, Linux Virtual Machines for the win on this one. Develop on Win/Mac, run on Linux. The problem with uploading six months of work to the live server and having it expire ignominiously goes away when you discover it the moment you made it. That was 2009, btw, the WAMP server got shot at sunrise.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible and actually very common for the vendor namespace. It's also possible in the last part of the class but less common because it results in slightly awkward class aliases like `vendor_extension/className` (though I personally prefer that over a senseless deep directory structure)

You have to use the capitalisation consistently whereever you refer to the module name `Vendor_Extension` and in the module directory in `app/code`.

You don't need to use the same capitalisation for model, block and helper aliases (i.e. everything that is usually all lowercase and can be an arbitrary unique string)